What is the solution to the following recurrence relation with square root: $T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+n$?
This here is the question,
$T(n) = T (\sqrt{n}) + n$
The Time complexity for this recurrence relation will be $\theta(\log_2(\log_2(n))$
). I do not understand how this works here. Can I anyone provide me with the valid answer for this question.

Do you mean time complexity of computing $T$ from the relation and $T(1)$? What do you do if $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer?

This question doesn't appear to be complete. If $n$ is supposed to be an integer (as the term "recurrence relation" suggests), then should the right-hand side be $T(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)+n$? Is there an initial condition? Or is this maybe a functional equation, in which $n$ is a non-negative real?

I suppose you are also missing the base case.

Can you provide more informations, like why are you asking this, where this question comes from and what you tried to solve this. Currently this is of the form "This is my problem. Solve it." and that does not meet the Math.SE standards.

Take $n = a^m, a>1, a \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ then the sequence can be recast  as
$$
R(m)=R(m/2)+a^m
$$
that with $m = 2^k$ can be recast again as
$$
S(k) = S(k-1) + a^{2^k}
$$
with solution
$$
S(k) = c_0+\sum_{j=1}^k a^{2^j}
$$
now going backwards
$$
R(m) = c_0+\sum_{j=1}^{\log_2 m}a^{2^j}
$$
and
$$
T(n) = c_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(\log_a n)}a^{2^i}
$$
Here
$$
a^{2^{\log_2(\log_a n)}} = n
$$
hence  $O(n)\le T(n) \lt O(n^2)$

so $a^{2^i}$ grows so rapidly that, when summed, only the last term matters.
